# Using day trading limits

Tags: limit, trading, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

I would like to set up a backtesting strategy which allows me to trade up to a certain stock position such as 10000.

Therefore, I can go long or short up to 10000 but not over.

I have currently set up a backtesting strategy but I cannot work out how to stop it trading once it hits a limit.

If I buy 10000 then I should only be allowed to sell and not buy.

I have this:

```
df_tradable["Trade"].groupby(df_tradable["Date"]).cumsum()
```

This adds up all of my trades for a day.
(Trade is +1 or -1 depending if buy or sell)

I can set up another check which only adds up P&L when my day traded is less than 10000 however I want to be able to sell again.

Is there an easy way to set this up please?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot exceed $1m per day? Please explain a bit further. It would be easier for everyone. What does the "trade" column represent, the market price? I am guessing it represents the profit made for a certain trade, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry. $1m is dollar traded  limit.  So if stock is $10 then I can buy or sell quantity of 100,000 of a stock.

Comment: Trade is number shares bought or sold * stock price

Comment: Thanks, ok, I'm guessing that you're trading a single stock, right? Otherwise you need to provide another column. But still, I'm unsure what exactly you are trying to achive. Are you saying your .cumsum() shouldn't exceed $1m at any point? Or are you running a sort of an algorithm and only want to sum the trades that happened before the $1m cutoff? Or maybe you want to only sum the negative(short) trades after the $1m? If it's yes to the last question, just do:

    df_tradable["Trade"].groupby(df_tradable["Date"]).cumsum()[df_tradable.Trade < 1000000 | df_tradable.Trade <0]

Comment: Hi,  I have amended the text above to try to make it more clear.  I hope it helps.  Sorry for the confusion.